# get Value of exact the one ngFor element ive entered the value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i have tried alot but iam out of ideas.

I have following code

HTML:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  array = [{id: 1}, {id: 2},{id: 3}]
value: string;
  printValue(value: any){
    console.log(value);
    var containputiner = document.querySelector("#"+value);
    this.value = containputiner.value;
    console.log(this.value);
  }
}
```

TS:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array">
  <input id="id_{{item.id}}" />
  <button type="button" (click)="printValue('id_'+item.id)"> button {{item.id}}</button>
  <div>{{value}}</div>
</div>
```

What i want to have is   **{{value}}** only be filled for each input field.
I do not want always the same value when entering ANY input field saved in this variable.
Input field 1 should fill   {{value}}1, input field 2 should fill   {{value}}2

Can someone help me out ?

https://dynamic-input-id-zgqzgi.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Have you looked up ngModel https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel ??

Comment: i couldnt understand if that helps me out, i thought about an index with a method returning the value for chosen input

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  
  array = [
    {
      id: 1, 
      value: ''
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      value: ''
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      value: ''
    }
  ]

  printValue(id: number){
    console.log('id: ', id);
    console.log('this.array: ', this.array[id]);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array, let i = index">
  <input [id]="'id_' + item.id" [(ngModel)]="item.value"/>
  <button type="button" (click)="printValue(i)"> 
    button {{item.id}}
  </button>
</div>
```

I prepared a Stackblitz for you (yours unfortunately didn't open):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eugxqe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: The solution is not exactly the angular way. I prefer the reactive forms: 

https://stackblitz.com/angular/eybokrejblk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts 

You will see that way you'll have an easier validation on the form itself.

See docs here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: first of all thanks, what i want now is the value i entered displaying below the input field, but each field should have other values ofcouse.

Comment: I updated the StackBlitz. Now it writes the value in the div inside of the button. You can place wherever you like (inside of your component)

Comment: thanks, can you update this with value from a dropdown too? mabye with an method something like getDropdownValue($event) saving this in a variable in TS and read it out of it exactly for one ngfor element?